# CSS for a vertical Navbar

Tags: css, navbar

Trying to create a vertical navbar using CSS3.  Like the following sample used by the website "Smokey Bones"  [Smokey Bones](http://smokeybones.com/)

However, I cannot use a Wordpress site or plugin.  I need to do this with HTML5/CSS3 & can use some javascript.  Anyone know where I can find a useable working vertical Navbar?  I'd need the CSS code.

Note that a simple vertical list of links will not work.  Also it should be Responsive.

Comment: I think before asking for help in stackoverflow. You should try first by your self and show us what you did. So we can help you and try to debug your code. If you don't try something first. People won't help you. Read this article by Gordon Zhy => https://medium.com/@gordon_zhu/how-to-be-great-at-asking-questions-e37be04d0603

Comment: I have 2 different examples: both working.  This is from   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sidenav_buttons      Unfortunately it will only permit 400 charaters in code:

Answer (score 0):

Just use similar CSS

```
.mainNav li {
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
}
```

jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nowak2009/ruho59wy/3/)